# Laravel project auto refresh after changes

Tags: laravel, browser

Does anyone know if there is a way to run the code changes in a Laravel project **without** refreshing the page every time.

I know that to see the changes I need to

```
php artisan serve
```

but I do it every time and it is kind of frustrating.

Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can achieve this with [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/mix).

According to [this part](https://laravel.com/docs/mix#browsersync-reloading) of the documentation, you need to edit your `webpack.mix.js` file, and add this to the end:

```
mix.browserSync('127.0.0.1:8000');
```

It needs to match to the output of the `php artisan serve` command, where you found a line something like this:

```
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
```

After this, you have to run the `php artisan serve`, and the `npm run watch` command simultaneously. You must leave to run both commands while you edit your files.

Note: The first time you run the `npm run watch`, it installs additional components. But the command output is quite clear on that. If everything is in order, Laravel Mix automatically opens your browser with `http://localhost:3000`, or something like this.

Comment: I had to run `php artisan serve` first so that it would work. Using `Laravel 8`

Comment: `npx mix watch` and `npm run watch` are equivalent for this

Answer (score 6):

**add in webpack.mix.js file in laravel**

```
mix.browserSync('127.0.0.1:8000');
```

**then run this command**

```
> npm install browser-sync browser-sync-webpack-plugin@2.0.1 --save-dev --production=false
```

**after this run npm run watch**

```
> Browsersync automatic run your port 3000
```

Comment: I saw a mistake at filename. Should be:
`webpack.mix.js`, with **i** instead of **a**.

Answer (score 3):

First make sure you install [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/), After that  install laravel-mix

```
npm install --save-dev laravel-mix
```

create `webpack.mix.js` file in root folder for your project and add to it

```js
const mix =require('laravel-mix')
mix.browserSync('127.0.0.1:8000');
```

Open package.json file and add to script section:

```json
  "scripts": {
        "watch": "mix watch"
    }
```

Run laravel project

```
php artisan serve
```

To update laravel project auto when you make changes run in another terminal:

```
npm run watch
```

## Updated from Laravel 9.x

you can use `vite` instead of `laravel-mix`, you should run this command to install vite:

```
npm install
```

Without any configuration, The next line of code will include auto in master page, If you want to include in another master page like admin, you can  write it to auto refresh  when make changes:

```
@vite(['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'])
```

After installing vite, run this command

```
npm run dev
```

And run

```
php artisan serve
```

For more information, [view docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can use [Laravel Mix](https://gist.github.com/vades/28f7e487192b3fbb61c429efd200cf1f)

- Ensure that Node.js and NPM are installed:

> run node -v and npm -v.

- Install Laravel Mix

> npm install.

- Install browser-sync and browser-sync-webpack-plugin

> npm install browser-sync browser-sync-webpack-plugin --save-dev --production=false

- Open webpack.mix.js and add this line

> mix.browserSync('127.0.0.1:8000');.

- Run Project with these two commands: The **npm run watch** command will continue running in your terminal and watch all relevant CSS and JavaScript files for changes. Webpack will automatically recompile your assets when it detects a change

> php artisan serve. and then npm run watch.

Answer (score 1):

**Live Server** extension can help u easy archive this.

1. Install **[Live Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhCBD.png)** from ****VSCode** market place**.
2. Install the [**Live Server Extension**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-server-web-extension/fiegdmejfepffgpnejdinekhfieaogmj/) in the **Chrome** **browser** then edit like [**this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAE3v.png).

*Note: On **Live Server
Web Chrome Extension** The **Actual Server Address** is where

`php artisan serve` running, by default is

> **http://127.0.0.1:8000**

And the **Live Server Address** is where your VSCode **Live Server** running ( mine is http://127.0.0.1:5500 )

3. Open **VSCode**, press

> **Ctrl + Shift + P**

and enter "**change live**" then choose like [**this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oZ7W.png), then choose your **Workspace** (your PHP file's parent directory)

*Note: whenever you change your **Workspace** remember to do this **Step 3**

4. Done, whenever you run the `php artisan serve` command, remember to turn on **Live Server** on **VSCode** like [**this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZW96.png). Your browser will auto refresh after your **VSCode** does auto save.

Enjoy ;)