# laravel 6 didn't watch view sub folder

Tags: php, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix, livereload

I got an issue up here.
I'm using laravel 6, and laravel mix only live reloads when the PHP file is in **"views"** folder directly but, when I make a subfolder in it, it pretends as nothing happened when I make any changes in the files below's it, I have to refresh the web page in the browser every time I make a change.
by the way, I'm using the command `npm run watch`, and the results have no errors in it.
so, the order of my folders looks like this:

resources

- views
- - file1.blade.php
- - file2.blade.php
- - folder
- - - subfile1.blade.php
- - - subfile2.blade.php

Comment: How do you listen to file changes in the views directory in the first place? Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50657132/11801683) it works for sub folders as well.

Comment: I'm really using the approach that's been attached in the link in your comment but it only works in the views direct files not when  I use the files inside folders, and this is my browser sync in my webpack.mix.js file :::    mix.browserSync('127.0.0.1:8000');