# Laravel 8 refreshes the webpage automatically how to disable it?

Tags: html, jquery, laravel, webpack

I have tried the webpack solution written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49392001/laravel-project-auto-refresh-after-changes?newreg=d6c28499a60e4105a97d64cc1b6864b1) but got no luck and tried to check the answer of my question on laracast as well as on stackoverflow but didn't get the solution.

Because I'm adding a input field dynamically using JQuery and it is disappearing that input field. I'm using Laravel 8.

**composer.json**

```
    {
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
        "laravel/jetstream": "^1.6",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.6",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "livewire/livewire": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

**package.json**

```
    {
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/ui": "^0.6.0",
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "browser-sync": "^2.26.13",
        "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^1.8.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
    }
}
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
        const mix = require('laravel-mix');
    
    /*
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     | Mix Asset Management
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |
     | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
     | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
     | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
     |
     */
    
    mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
        .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
            require('postcss-import'),
            require('tailwindcss'),
        ])
        .webpackConfig(require('./webpack.config'));
    
    mix.browserSync('127.0.0.1:8000');
```

Comment: needs to exclude the meta tag of refresh after 30 sec from the head tag. remove or comment this tag 
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove (or remark) last line from your ***webpack.mix.js***

> mix.browserSync('127.0.0.1:8000');