# URL paths that work in Vue 2 and Laravel 8?

Tags: html, css, laravel, vue.js

I'm working on a `vue/laravel` project and can't use one `url path` for both the dev environment (`npm run hot`) and production environment (`php artisan serve`).

This `CSS` example works only for `php artisan`:

```
background: url("../images/image.png")
```

while this only works for `npm run hot`:

```
background: url("/public/images/image.png")
```

Is there a method that works in both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up just using `php artisan serve` with `hot reload` instead of using `npm run hot`. Now I have only one dev environment. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49392001/laravel-project-auto-refresh-after-changes) how to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you should refer to from `src`. So moving the `image.png` to `/src/images/image.png` it would be something like `background: url("@/images/image.png")`, as `@` refers to `src`.

---

EDIT: Approach with `laravel` and `vue-cli`

If you need to set up different path´s for your enviroments, `vue-cli` could be your choice. This gives you the possibility to create a `vue.config.js` and set up a `publicPath` for your enviroments.

Further Information: [Integrate Laravel with a Vue CLI app](https://dev.to/mtdalpizzol/integrate-laravel-and-vue-cli-app-with-hot-module-replacement-and-no-backend-api-4h76)

Comment: Is `src` not a thing of past Laravel versions? Laravel `8` has a `resources` folder with all files that user works with. Unfortunately `@` does not seem to work with `resources` folder. And even if I create a `src` folder I am getting `errors` thrown at me by Laravel `8`.

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov Maybe `vue-cli` makes your needs possible. I edited my answer. Let me know if this helped you.